# Playing videos using flash 'offline'

Tags: flash, video, flv, mp4

I'm building a site that needs to work both online (served in a browser using http://), and offline (served in a browser using file:///). The site is using basic HTML, but needs to be able to play FLV or MP4 videos. There are many video players that work online, but getting a player to work on the users machine is more problematic. Every one I have tried either doesn't work or shows a message about adding the flash movie to my trusted files in flash player.

I've tried:

- jwPlayer
- FlowPlayer
- MediaElementJS
- Lean Back Player
- projekktor
- Strobe Media Playback

Has anybody experienced a similar problem? Does anybody have a suggestion for alternatives that may work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a fair bit more research I've found another player that allows playback offline - http://www.jcplayer.com/. Sure there are others out there somewhere, but this serves my needs!